# Accessing WCF in Azure by $.ajax yields "NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101"

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf, azure

I've tried both sync and async approaches. I've tested all the different things suggested in many threads but still, I keep getting the error above.

For IE I get "*No transport*" and in FF a scary looking "*Exception... "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)*".

When I access the service from the URL line in my browsers, I get see the returned text, se the service is up and running. (*MyCloud.azurewebsites.net/MyService.svc/Ping*)

But it doesn't work when I try to access it using this JS.

```javascript
$.ajax({
  cache: false,
  async: false, //have tried true too
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://MyCloud.azurewebsites.net/MyService.svc/Ping",
  datatype: "text",
  success: function (response) { ... },
  error: function (xhr, requestStatus, errorText) { ... }
});
```

I've tested different browsers (other than Chrome). I tested declaring a different end point with some alteration to the security (*transport* instead of *none*) because of the CORS issue. I still end up getting errors. And looking for those only brings more confusion.

Now, that I've been fighting this issue for over a day, I decided to structure the trouble-shooting.

- Is the above JS correct at all?
- Are the below end point definition and service declaration correct as well?
- What more can I test? How can I probe the issue?

```xml
<endpoint name="UrlEndPoint"
          behaviorConfiguration="UrlEndPointBehavior"
          address=""
          binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="MyNamespace.IMyService"/>

<behavior name="UrlEndPointBehavior">
  <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
</behavior>
```

```csharp
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Ping", Method = "GET")]
String Ping();
```

I'm totally lost, sick and tired at the moment. A push in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Is this a cross-domain request?

Comment: @MikeBrant Yes. The the service's on Azure and the call can come from anywhere. I've read that some people had issues with CORS but as I mentioned it in the questions, that gave me only headache.   :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a cross-site scripting error.  You need to call a server-side handler (proxy) to handle the request to the Azure environment.  So, your AJAX call would look something more like this:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: 'some/local/server-side/url/to/handle/the/call/to/"http://MyCloud.azurewebsites.net/MyService.svc/Ping",
   datatype: "text",
   success: function (response) { // handle response here from server-side proxy here },
   error: function (xhr, requestStatus, errorText) { ... }
 });
```

The problem is that you cannot make calls to external domains due to XSS (cross-site scripting) limitations in the browser.  This is a security precaution implemented by your browser of choice.